# Sending string to another computer through serial port

Tags: c#, vb.net, serial-port

I'm trying to use a VB.Net Winform to send a string through the COM port to another computer. I have an RS232 COM port on the computer with the application. I then have a Serial to USB adapter that is plugged into the other computer's USB port.

I am using SerialPort from .NET and my application opens the COM port and initializes it. Then when I use `mySerialPort.Write(string)`, the Rx light on the MOXA serial to usb adapter blinks, as if it is receiving the data.

However, if I have notepad open on the computer that's receiving the data, nothing prints out.

Essentially, what I'm trying to do is have the user push a button that will send a barcode (as a string) to the other computer. But I can't figure out how to get the other computer to read the string and print it to notepad or whatever textfield has focus.

I'm limited on what I can install on the receiving computer because it runs Unix.

Comment: So... you have a program to send, do you also have a program to receive? And is it running on the receiving computer? If not, what do you expect the receiving computer to do with the serial data?

Comment: Yeah, I see the problem but don't know how to solve it. If I plug in a USB barcode scanner into the receiving computer, then scan a barcode, it prints it to whatever textfield is in focus. It appears that the scanner device installs a keyboard emulator driver to perform that read/print function.

Comment: I was hoping to emulate that sort of input using a com transmission from the computer that's running my vb application.

Comment: Yep, the USB barcode scanner adds software that knows what to do with the data, and I doubt you could "trigger" it via COM port. To do something similar, you would need to write software for the receiving end.